# reduce the time taken by application packet to reduce ethernet interface on windows?

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, lan, packet

How do I possibly reduce the time taken by an application packet e.g.like http from a browser to ethernet of same computer on windows 7? I will be programming in visual studio in c++  in few days. I will creating a possibly lan network to send multicast messages between computers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you may see some speed increase by using "http://127.0.0.1/" URLs.  The 127.a.b.c IP addresses are reserved for "local" IP addresses. At least for some Unixes and Linux, using a 127.0.0.1 address keeps the packet from actually going to the NIC: there's a short-circuit code path the keeps the packet "inside" the computer.  I know so little about Windows 7, and Microsoft has a history of creating really odd network "shortcuts", "performance optimizations" and sof roth, that this could be totally wrong for Windows 7.